# How to check if there is a missing argument

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
def suma(num1,num2):

    if(isinstance(num1,int)) or (isinstance(num2,int)) :
       if num1<0 or num2<0:
            print("iavo")
       elif num1!=int(num1)or num2!=int(num2):
            print("iao")
       else:
            suma_a = num1+num2
            return suma_a
    else:
        print("ia")
```

I need to check whether there is a `num1` or `num2`. If there is none, the program should print that there is a missing argument.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not assign default values and a user did not supply two args you would get a `TypeError: suma() missing 1 required positional argument` before you got into the function at all:

```
def suma(num1=None,num2=None):
     # make sure user has entered two args and both are numbers
    if num1 is None or num2 is None:
        return "You Must choose two numbers"
    # rest of code
```

Answer (score 4):

That function will throw an error if you don't send both numbers. There is no way to leave out an argument in your function.

If you did i.e. something like:

```
def summ(a, b=None):
    return a+b
```

then you could leave out b, however this will throw an unsupported operand error again because you can't add a number and None.

You can check if you have all numbers present if you're calling that function in the scope of some other function, or in a class, you can wrap it in a try except block and try to handle the error like shown in the dumbest example possible:

```
try: 
    summ(1)
except: 
    print("Missing arguments, you can't add numbers and None in Python!"\
          " Please send b.")
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is what assertions are useful for.](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) In your declaration:

```
def suma(num1,num2):
    pass
```

if someone calls `suma` with only one argument then the function will throw an error.

You can add extra checks by asserting the form of the arguments, like so:

```
def suma(num1,num2):
    assert (num1 is not None)
    assert (num2 is not None)
```

Answer (score -1):

`None` values return False on logical comparisons.

A compact way to check for **both arguments missing** could be:

```
def suma(num1,num2):
    if not(num1 or num2):
        print('Missing both arguments')
```

Which is what you initially asked.

But as was pointed out by others, even if you miss just one argument your function will throw an exception.

So if you want to check for **any argument missing**, you can do the following:

```
def suma(num1,num2):
    if not(num1 and num2):
        print('Missing at least one argument')
```

**This will not work correctly if you expect 0 values for your arguments**, since they will evaluate to False on logical inspections. In that case you can use the more formal methods of:

```
not(num1 is None or num2 is None)
not(num1 is None and num2 is None)
```

Comment: This isn't testing for missing arguments, this is testing for provided arguments that have the value `None`.